# Velocity -- get customfield value for Jira subtask

Tags: jira, velocity

I'm building a Velocity script for Jira but I need some help with this.

I have some Subtasks in a Parent Jira ticket. I want to get the values for certain customfield WITHIN that subtask.

This is what I've tried:

```
#foreach($subTask in $issue.getSubTaskObjects())
     $cf = $getCustomFieldObject(customfield_11758) 
     $subTask.getCustomFieldValue($cf)
#end
```

But this doesn't seem to work. My goal is to have customfield_11758 (in the subtask) to print out its value in a script.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

getCustomFieldObject is a method of CustomFieldManager: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/issue/CustomFieldManager.html

I see that $customFieldManager is available for JIRA velocity email templates: https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-architecture/jira-templates-and-jsps/velocity-context-for-email-templates but I am not sure if it's injected to non email templates. So try $customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject(customfield_11758). If there is no $customFieldManager string "$customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject(customfield_11758)" will be printed.

In this case you need to make sure that your workflow action has either a getter for CustomFieldManager and then you use it like:

```
$customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject($type)
```

or has a method that wraps customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject and then you invoke the method from the template.